# Override 'Blog pages show at most' and show all posts for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm trying to overwrite the default 'Blog pages show at most' which is set to 5 posts. I have a custom post type called 'FAQs', which has the argument `'posts_per_page' => 999` in the query for getting all the posts of this type, however I can't seem to override the default restriction in the WordPress setting. My code for the FAQ query is below, which works on my local machine (MAMP) but not when I upload it to live. how do I show all posts of that type?

```
                  <?php

                      wp_reset_query();

                      // Query for getting custom taxonomy 'FAQ Type' of custom post type 'FAQs'
                      $cat_args = array (
                        'taxonomy' => 'faq_type',
                        'exclude' => array(12),
                        'posts_per_page' => 999,
                        //'show_all' => true,
                        'orderby' => 'simple_page_ordering_is_sortable'
                      );
                      $categories = get_categories ( $cat_args );

                      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

                        //wp_reset_query();

                        $cat_query = null;

                        // Query for getting posts of custom post type 'FAQs'
                        $args = array (
                          'post_type' => 'faq',
                          'faq_type' => $category->slug,
                          'posts_per_page' => 999,
                          //'show_all' => true,
                          'orderby' => 'simple_page_ordering_is_sortable',
                        );
                        $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

                        <?php echo "<h2>". $category->name ."</h2>"; ?>

                        <ul id="resident-accordion" class="accordion white-bg-accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true" role="tablist">

                        <?php

                          while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $cat_query->the_post();
                            ?>

                              <li class="accordion-item faq-content <?php //if ($firstLoop === true) { echo "is-active"; }?>" data-accordion-item>
                                <a href="#" class="accordion-title" role="tab"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                                <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                              </li>

                            <?php
                          } //wp_reset_query();
                          wp_reset_postdata(); //End WHILE

                        echo "</ul>";

                        } //End IF
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        //wp_reset_query();
                      } //End FOR
                  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this code below :

```
<?php
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'faq_type',
    'exclude'  => array(7),
    'orderby'  => 'simple_page_ordering_is_sortable'
);

$categories = get_terms( $cat_args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'faq',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // load all posts
        'orderby'        => 'simple_page_ordering_is_sortable',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'faq_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $category->slug
            )
        )
    );

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // enter the rest of your code below
}
```

Or you can use [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) to receive posts list.

```
<?php
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'faq_type',
    'exclude'  => array(7),
    'orderby'  => 'simple_page_ordering_is_sortable'
);

$categories = get_terms( $cat_args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
{
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'faq_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $category->slug,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
        'post_type'     => 'faq',
    ));

    // enter the rest of your code below
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, still displaying the max number of posts of 5

Comment: @Amesey I've update my answer, you can check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You found your answer by now I hope, but you were so close.

Instead of:

```php
'posts_per_page' => 999,
```

try:

```php
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

see: [Pagination Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters)